# Style a text field in JasperReports

Tags: styles, jasper-reports, ireport

I know how to apply inline style to Static Text in JasperReports. Can the same be done for Text Elements (text fields)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can apply style for ***`textField`*** elements.

#### iReport using

The sample of report's template:

```xml
<jasperReport ..>
    <style name="ColoredField" style="Default" forecolor="#FF0000">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <style/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    ...
    <detail>
        <band height="52" splitType="Stretch">
            <!--Using the style declared in this template-->
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="textWithStyle" style="ColoredField" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TASKS_SERIES}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <!--Basic formatting (set font and indent) using-->
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="textWithoutStyle" x="100" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TASKS_TASK}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <!--Markup using: styled-->
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="590" height="42"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The static text without any format.\nThe field's data with bold format<style isBold='true'>:" + $F{TASKS_SUBTASK} + "</style>\n<style isBold='true' isItalic='true' isUnderline='true'>The static underlined text with bold and italic format</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The quote from iReport Ultimate Guide about `markup` attribute:

> This ***`Markup`*** attribute allows you to format the text using a specific markup
>   language. This is extremely useful when you have to print some text
>   that is pre-formatted, that is, in HTML or RTF. Simple HTML style tags
>   (like  for bold and  for Italic) can be used in example to
>   highlight a particular chunk of the text. The possible values are as
>   follows:
>
> **None**
>  
>   No processing on the text is performed, and the text is printed
>   exactly like it is provided.
>
> **Styled**
>  
>   This markup is capable to format the text using a set of HTML-like tags and it is pretty popular in the Java environments. 
>   It allows to set a specific font for chunks of text, color, background, style and so on. 
>   It's often good enough to format the text programmatically.
>
> **HTML**
>  
>   If you want to print some HTML text into your report, this is what you need, but it's primary use is to format text, so don't expect to be able to print tables or add
>   images.
>
> **RTF**
>  
>   Setting the markup to this value, the content will be interpreted as RTF code. RTF is a popular document format stored in pure text. The little piece of text saying “this is a text formatted in RTF” in Illustration 19 has been generated using the string: 
>   {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0
>   Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 Swift;}} {*\generator Msftedit
>   5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 This is a text \f1\fs52 formatted \f0\fs20 in RTF\par } 
>   The string is actually an RTF file created using a simple word processor.
>
> **Report font**
>   This is the name of a preset font, from which will be taken all the character properties.
>   This attribute is deprecated and it is there only for compatibility
>   reason (that's why it the label is strukethrough. In order to define a
>   particular style of text to use all over your document, use a style.

The sample of using `markup` is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/index.html).

You can use `style` for setting:

Common properties

Graphics properties

Border and padding properties

Text properties

The another sample is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/templates/index.html#templates).

#### DynamicJasper API using

In case using [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/features/) API you can set style with help of [ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilder](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/ColumnBuilder.html) class:

```java
AbstractColumn columnState = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
.addColumnProperty("state", String.class.getName())
.addTitle("State").addWidth(new Integer(85))
.addStyle(detailStyle).addHeaderStyle(headerStyle).build();
```

The sample is [here](http://blog.junaedhalim.com/2010/02/dynamic-jasper-basics.html).

#### JasperReports API using

In case using [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) you can set style, for example, with help of [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base .JRBasePrintText](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBasePrintText.html) class:

```java
JRPrintText text = new JRBasePrintText(jasperPrint.getDefaultStyleProvider());
text.setStyle(boldStyle);
```

The sample is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/printservice/index.html).

Comment: I asked about inline style, which are possible with markup=styled. One just has to be careful to concatenate style strings with dynamic elements, like "<font face='Arial Black'>" + $P{param} + "</font>. Please update your answer.

Comment: @ipavlic Thank you for your remark. I've just add info about using `markup`. Thanks again

Comment: I have accepted your answer now that it includes the inline style options I have originally asked about. Thank you!

Comment: Why subreport won't use the given style then? etc. `<reportElement style="Calibri" ...` does not work.

Comment: Did you add style to the subreport?