# format the text style in text field iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to make some text in a text field bold. I visited http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/index.html but could not get the desired result. I am using text field right now but when I tried using styled/html, the compilation failed. So can you help me with this jrxml code snippet:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="590" height="42"/>
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The static text without any format.\nThe field's data with bold format<style isBold='true'>:" + $F{TASKS_SUBTASK} + "</style>\n<style isBold='true' isItalic='true' isUnderline='true'>The static underlined text with bold and italic format</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In this example: [Style a text field in Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135215/style-a-text-field-in-jasper), the text field expression is wrong for which compilation fails.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error have you got during compilation? Did you try the sample with `$F{TASKS_SUBTASK}` expression? The sample you talking about is working.

Comment: Thankx Alex for your reply i got my problem solved.

Comment: The problem solved by putting <b><u> inside text string

Answer (score 5):

This work good:

```
"<style isBold='true' pdfFontName='Helvetica-Bold'>" + $F{data} + "</style>"
```

for input data from datasource, or

```
<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">Bolt text</style>
```

only for some static text.

For Text-field set properties Markup = styled.

Answer (score 4):

in your view ireport designer.

click on the field and in the properties panel.: markup = styled selected

Right click on the fied. edit expression:

```
($F{fila1}.equals("c") ? "<style forecolor='red'>"+ $F{fila1}+"</style>" : $F{fila1})
```

or xml

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{fila1}.equals("c") ? "<style forecolor='red'>"+ $F{fila1}+"</style>" : $F{fila1})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<b> </b>` tags no longer work on text fields. Make sure that 'Styled text' is enabled for the text field and put this in the field expression.

```
<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">Text to be bold...</style>
```

The pdfFontName can be whatever you like.

If you are making text bold that is already in a string be sure to escape the above quotes with a backslash.

Comment: the text field option is: Markup --> "Styled"

Answer (score 1):

> I solved by putting  for bold and underline in input string

```
"<b><u> your text</u></b>"
```

Comment: set properties Markup = styled for embedded html tags in string as shown above

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem changing 'makup' text-field atribute to 'html'. Then in text-field expression use html tags like < b> < /b>. =D

Answer (score 0):

```
"<style isBold='true' pdfFontName='Helvetica-Bold'>" + $F{data} + "</style>"
```

what is done above simply

```
<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold">Bolt text</style>
```

> For Text-field set properties Markup = styled.

**see the screenshot below**
hope this helps !!!

[image]