# Jasper PDF Report not showing date between strong tag( <strong>) as bold

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I wrote a java program which will generate a pdf using jasper engine. I chose markup language as html while creating the jxml and when i send data with  tags it does'nt print bold output. But it only does for `<b>`. What settings i need to change inorder to print bold for strong tags in jasper report?

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8135922/876298) on similar post

Comment: @AlexK thanks for response. But i am actually looking for something like converting <strong>,<em> to <b>,<i> so that jasper engine will understand and do the appropriate style.