# JasperReports: Not support & sign when i use style

Tags: jasper-reports, stylesheet

Working in *JasperReports*:

```xml
<style pdfFontName="Helvetica-BoldOblique" isBold="true" isItalic="true" 
forecolor="red">Instruction and instruction</style>
```

Not Working in *JasperReports*:

```xml
<style pdfFontName="Helvetica-BoldOblique" isBold="true" isItalic="true"
forecolor="red">Instruction & instruction</style>
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used 
    &amp;amp; 
instead of "&" and it is working in jasper report.

```
<style pdfFontName="Helvetica-BoldOblique" isBold="true" isItalic="true"
forecolor="red">Instruction &amp;amp; instruction</style>
```

//In text filed i have used style tag.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                <reportElement
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    width="290"
                    height="15"
                    key="textField"
                    isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box topBorder="None" topBorderColor="#000000" leftBorder="None" leftBorderColor="#000000" rightBorder="None" rightBorderColor="#000000" rightPadding="5" bottomBorder="None" bottomBorderColor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" isStyledText="true">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[<style pdfFontName="Helvetica-BoldOblique" isBold="true" isItalic="true"
forecolor="red">Instruction &amp;amp; instruction</style>]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *`&amp;`* instead of using *`&`* symbol.

The working sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ... whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <style name="style1" forecolor="#FF0000" fontName="Serif" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
    <title>
        <band height="182" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="style1" x="27" y="15" width="515" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Instruction and instruction]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="style1" x="27" y="46" width="515" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Instruction & instruction]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="27" y="78" width="515" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold='true'>Instruction and instruction</style>]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="27" y="108" width="515" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold='true'>Instruction &amp; instruction</style>]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Note:** The ***styled*** *markup* is using in this sample.

The result will be:

[image: The preview in iReport]

---

For more details you can view [Creating Styled Text Using a Markup Language](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/index.html#markup) post and my answer on [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135922/876298) question.

Comment: Thanks, But it is still not working. If i write "&amp;" out of style tag it is working but, when i write it in style tag, it not works.

Comment: @IshwarPohani Can you add the exact snippet from your *jrxml* to your question? I'll try to check your expression

Comment: Alex, I have found solution which worked for me. May be you are right but not worked in my scenerio. What i have found, i have posted.