# How to give an '&' symbol in report with styled text and markup html

Tags: jasper-reports

As i have given a textfield with styled text and markup html

but the value comes with '&' symbol

Output :  1. the name comes with '&' symbol

[image: the name comes with '&' symbol]`

```
     2. then name doesn't comes without '&' symbol
```

[image]

How to overcome this problem with *iReport*?

P.S : I am using *iReport 3.0*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Not support & sign when i use style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024334/jasperreports-not-support-sign-when-i-use-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had came up with the answer by simply using  `&amp;` instead of using & symbol.