# How to set the textfield component position based on the other text(text come from DB, don't know the length) in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to do something like this with *JasperReports*:

*Hello Everyone, my name is **xxxxxxxxxxxx**, posting a question in **yyyyyy***

In the above text ***xxxxxxxxxxxx*** is dynamic which is coming from database so I don't know the length of that string but the rest of the text(starting from the comma,) should be present immediately after that. There should not be any space between ***xxxxxxxxxxx*** and comma(,).

FYI:Here I am using 4 textfields.

Comment: add text field like this `"my name is"+$F{name}+", posting a question in "+F{year}`

Comment: Thanks Mani,
For the first time I tried like this only(total text taken in one TextField).
But please note that the dynamic text(xxxxx..) should be in bold. In a single TextField I am unable to apply different styles. This is the reason that why I have taken in 4 separate TextFields.
I tried below solution but no use..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294372/use-multiple-fonts-for-a-single-text-field-in-jasper-reports 

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135215/style-a-text-field-in-jasperreports)

Answer (score 0):

Try Markup for TextField

Ex:

```
<!--Markup using: styled-->
<textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="590" height="42"/>
    <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The static text without any format.\nThe field's data with bold format<style isBold='true'>:Mani, here im bold</style>\n<style isBold='true' isItalic='true' isUnderline='true'>The static underlined text with bold and italic format</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Here add your fields and styles as per your requirement.

for full reference on Markup for Textfield visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135922/2750968) SO Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a parameter like "name", than the expression of your textfield should be something like:

```
"Hello Everyone, my name is " + $P{name} + "....."
```

This should work.