# Set font for variable in Jasper Report expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set font for the value of variable $V{Payment Frequency} in a Text Field, using this expression but to no vail

```
"Payment frequency is <style isBold='true' forecolor='blue'>$V{Payment Frequency}</style>"
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working (correct) expression in your case is:

```xml
"Payment frequency is <style isBold='true' forecolor='blue'>" + $V{Payment Frequency} + "</style>"
```

You should append the value of variable as the `String` in `Java` language.

Your expression is like this block in *Java*:

```java
String paymentFrequency = "some value";
String textFieldValue = "Payment frequency is <style isBold='true' forecolor='blue'>$V{Payment Frequency}</style>";
```

And my expression:

```java
String paymentFrequency = "some value";
String textFieldValue = "Payment frequency is <style isBold='true' forecolor='blue'>" + paymentFrequency + "</style>";
```

---

For more details about markup you can look at [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135215/876298) post.