# Conditional alignment of textfields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am designing a template for an image which will have the product price (being taken from a datasource). If the product has a strikeout-price, the image displays it followed by the current price. If there is no strikeout-price, only the current price is displayed.

All works fine except the alignment of the prices when there is no strikeout-price. Both prices need to be horizontally together, and center-aligned in either case. But I am not able to center-align the current price textfield, if the strikeout-price is null/blank. When there is a strikeout-price, it is not a problem, as both textfields are aligned properly in the designer view.

Also, how can I put conditional formatting based on the availability of strikout-price? If the strikeout-price is not present, the font color of the current price should be different than when there is a strikeout-price.

EDIT: Images of both cases below

When Strikeout-price is available, this is how it should look:

[image: When Strikeout-price is available, this is how it should look]

When Strikeout-price is not available, the textfield with price shown should be center-aligned:

[image: When Strikeout-price is not available, the textfield with price shown should be center-aligned]

Comment: Can you illustrate your issue with images?

Comment: @AlexK added the images. 1st one is how it should be. 2nd one should have the price aligned as the strikeout-price is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easy do it with help of [Conditional Styles](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles).

#### The sample

The test *csv* datasource:

```
name,price,discount_price
Shirt,"100,00","90,99"
Trousers,"80,00",
"Sun glasses","199,99","120,00"
```

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="two_textfields_one_on_other" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="cb5d2807-1ef9-4ffb-8df8-fcb781054bb0">
    <style name="priceStyle" hAlign="Left">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{discount_price} == null || $F{discount_price} == 0.]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#3333FF" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Top"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="discount_price" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="93ad241e-5257-4664-b3ab-f6448f786775" x="0" y="0" width="114" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6b53f6c6-5d48-4879-8934-d446150e1375" style="priceStyle" positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="114" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{discount_price} != null && $F{discount_price} > 0.) ?  "<style isStrikeThrough='true'>"+ $F{price} + " $</style>  " + $F{discount_price} + " $" : $F{price} + " $"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

In this sample I changed the *forecolor* of text (make it as *Blue*) and the text's horizontal alignment (make it as *Central*, the default is *Left*) in case when the *discount price* is absent (not set or equals 0.0).

The design in *iReport* looks like this:

[image]

And the result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

---

Note:

For better formatting I have used the [markup syntax](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/index.html#markup) in my sample. You can also read about styling in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135215/876298)