# How to subscript a field in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

How to make a field to show as a SubScript or to show the field below the text base line.
I have to use USPSIMBStandard font when the font applies to the report the information that should print jumps up or hide the upper area of the text field, when i copy the whatever portion of the information to the word and subscript it, it shows correctly.

Comment: You can use another text to show SubScript.

Comment: Irony is that i have to use only USPSIMBStandard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use *styled markup* for solving this task and the `<sub>` tag for subscript text and the `<sup>` tag for the superscript text.

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_markup" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c3c991dc-b3f2-4d45-b429-821e33c5324d">
    <title>
        <band height="55" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="6b947a69-22bb-4a63-9e56-cacc75747df0" x="115" y="17" width="324" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="styled">
                    <font isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text with<sup>superscript</sup> \nText with<sub>subscript</sub>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

***Notes:***

- You can find sample about using *markup* in [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135215/876298) post
- More info about markup is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html)