# How to prevent wrapping of a line of text in Jasperreports

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I have a line of text which reads "International ID". But whenever I am to display in in my Jasperreport to PDF, it will sometimes be spread across two lines like this: 
"International
ID". Is there a way to prevent wrapping in like in html I would use

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap">Long line with no breaks</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give sufficient width to the field "International ID" so that it won't wrap up in any exported format. Also check this with different languages (If you are supporting multiple languages).

About the HTML text part, you can style textField elements using different markups like "Styled", "HTML", "RTF" etc. See [Style a text field in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135215/style-a-text-field-in-jasperreports) for details.

However, HTML markup supports very basic HTML tags like `<p>, <br>, <color>` etc. It won't support `style="white-space: nowrap"`.

So you can either:

1. Increase the width of textField  OR
2. Let the text cut-off by setting `isStretchWithOverflow="false"` (This is not recommended mostly)

Answer (score 0):

My approach was this: (Excel nowrap in Jasper Report)

```
<reportElement key="staticText-5" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="70" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true"/>
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
</reportElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasperreports appears to be honoring `&nbsp;` combined with `<textElement markup="html"/>`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="nbsp" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="77c97c1b-90ba-40a8-a5c3-f88b8a48a585">
    <title>
        <band height="130">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="69" y="23" width="141" height="30" uuid="cd0cc386-988e-422f-83ba-744ee7d32d7d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="80" width="140" height="30" uuid="9b26682f-8ebd-4b40-87d3-f1c9827eedfd"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The quick brown fox jumps&nbsp;over the lazy dog"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```