# Style Tag & <br> tag don't work together in Jasper Report

Tags: html, css, jasper-reports

Currently, I have a text field in my jasper report with multiple style tags for different parts of the text.

```
<textField>
        <reportElement x="9" y="2" width="403" height="126"/>
        <textElement markup="styled"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA['Hi <style size="32">User</style>How <br> <style size="12">are</style> you? ']]></textFieldExpression>
 </textField>
```

Is there a work around to work with styled markup as well as html markup?

Comment: ? fontSize ? instead of Size ?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_styles.htm

Comment: @CarolMcKay: I took your suggestion and added missing quotes to the end of the string 
<textElement markup="html"/>
     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA['Hi <style fontSize="32">User</style>How <style fontSize="12">are</style> you?']]></textFieldExpression>
it still did not work :( 
So finally
i changed it styled markup  it worked but when i added tags like <br> tag it messed it up  again :( 
i have edited the code please check.And also thank you for your time :)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135215/style-a-text-field-in-jasperreports